# Build and Debug Excel add-in using XLW Project and Visual Studio 2022 C++

Tags: c++, excel-addins, xlw

I am creating an Excel add-in using the [XLW](https://github.com/xlw/xlw) project on GitHub in Visual Studio 2022 C++.

I have done the following:

Create a solution MyFunction which contains two projects MyFunction and XLW.

In MyFunction, Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type is set to Static Library.

In MyFunction,

### my_header.h

```
#pragma once

double EchoDouble(double x);
```

### my_source.cpp

```
#include "my_header.h"

double EchoDouble(double x)
{
    return x;
}
```

In XLW, the XLW package is installed via NuGet Package Manager, and

- Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type is set to Dynamic Library.
- Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories is set to the folder which contains the solution.
- Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directiories is set to the folder which contains MyFunction.lib.
- Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies is set to MyFunction.lib.

In XLW,

### cppinterface.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <xlw/MyContainers.h>
#include <xlw/CellMatrix.h>
#include <xlw/DoubleOrNothing.h>
#include <xlw/ArgList.h>  
    
using namespace xlw;

//<xlw:libraryname=MyTestLibrary


double MyEchoDouble(double x);

#endif
```

### source.cpp

```
#include "cppinterface.h"
#include "MyFunction/my_header.h"

#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

double MyEchoDouble(double x)
{
    return EchoDouble(x);
}
```

MyFunction is built first and then XLW. Load the generated add-in XLW.xll in Excel and MyEchoDouble works.

To debug, I can do Debug -> Attach to Process -> Attach to Native code and select the Excel instance. It works fine.

Alternatively, I do

- Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command is set to the path for EXCEL.EXE
- Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command Arguments is set to $(TargetPath)
- Set XLW as startup project.

Press F5, I get the error message:

### Exception Thrown

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE8496B74B in EXCEL.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

### Frame not in module

The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location.

My questions are

1. Is the way I set up the projects correct? What I want to achieve is that all functions are implemented in MyFunction project. Then corresponding Excel functions are done in XLW project, and the add-in is generated by the XLW project.
2. What went wrong with the alternative debugging method?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I built the xll using same configuires as you, but I had not change configuration properties. I do the same things like in video contained github repo. Please tell me if you solve it